# Checkbox value is refreshed after page reload in node JS

Tags: node.js, checkbox, backend, mern

"I am creating TODO list using Node as backend. after adding every new item, a checkbox is also generating in front of them so I can apply "CSS line-through" to let user know that item is done or of no use. But when I add another item, the page refreshes and that checkbox is unchecked as I am not storing that value anywhere. Can you tell me how to store the value of that checkbox in the backend?

HTML -

```
<div class="box" >  
    <% for (var i=0; i<newListItems.length; i++) { %>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox">
        <p> <%= newListItems[i] %> </p>
    </div>
    <% } %>
    <form action="/" method="post" class="item">
        <input class="inputBox" type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New item" autocomplete="off" required="required"> 
        <button type="submit" name="list" value=<%= listTitle%>> +</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Node JS -

const items = [];

app.post("/", function(req, res){

```
let item = req.body.newItem;
    items.push(item);
    res.redirect("/");
```

});

Answer (score 1):

The answer involves a lot of code, so I will give you a set of steps that can help in your case.

1. You need to change your data scheme. Currently looks like you are just storing the string in an array of items. You need to change it to be array of objects. Each object should have the field `task` and `done`. So you could know which task is done or not.

   ```
   app.post("/", function(req, res) {
       let item = req.body.newItem;
       items.push({ name: item, done: false });
       res.redirect("/");
   });
   ```
2. Next step will be adding an endpoint that will be changing the `done` field of an array item to `true`.
3. Then on a front-end you will need to write some JS code that will be sending an HTTP request to the endpoint that marks the task as done. You need to use AJAX call for that, for example, NPM package `axios`.
4. Change the template to reflect the changes to the data. e.g. instead of  `<%= newListItems[i] %>` do `<%= newListItems[i].name %>` and add logic to render checked checkbox based on `done` property.

It worth to mention, that you should not store data in memory, because once the process is done, you will lose your data. It is okay for learning purposes, but in production, you should use a database.